# conditional query with two tables Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have below mentioned two tables:

```
Table1
ID        key          Val1         Date1
A-1       xyz-ze       AA           2018-10-01 15:16:20
A-1       xyz-ze       AC           2018-10-02 18:19:40
A-2       xyi-ze       BV           2018-07-01 15:16:20
A-2       xyi-ze       CR           2018-03-01 19:22:37
A-2       xyi-ze       BR           2018-10-03 21:17:24

Table2
ID        key          Val2         Date2
A-1       xyz-ze       AA           2018-10-01 15:16:20
A-2       xyi-ze       BR           2018-10-03 22:47:56
```

By using above tables i want to fetch `Val1` and `Val2`, but `Val1` should be oldest value (Considering the `Date1`) and then matching `Val1` with `Val2` and giving status based on that.

Required output:

```
ID    key     Val1  Val2 Date1                Date2                Status
A-1   xyz-ze  AA    AA   2018-10-01 15:16:20  2018-10-01 15:16:20  TRUE
A-2   xyi-ze  CR    BR   2018-03-01 19:22:37  2018-10-01 15:16:20  FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.`key`, t1.Val1,  t1.Date1, t2.Date1
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 
   ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.`key` = t2.`key` AND t2.Date1 < t1.Date1
```

to get:

```
ID  key     Val1    Date1                   Date1
----------------------------------------------------------------
A-1 xyz-ze  AA      2018-10-01T15:16:20Z    (null)
A-1 xyz-ze  AC      2018-10-02T18:19:40Z    2018-10-01T15:16:20Z
A-2 xyi-ze  CR      2018-03-01T19:22:37Z    (null)
A-2 xyi-ze  BV      2018-07-01T15:16:20Z    2018-03-01T19:22:37Z
A-2 xyi-ze  BR      2018-10-03T21:17:24Z    2018-03-01T19:22:37Z
A-2 xyi-ze  BR      2018-10-03T21:17:24Z    2018-07-01T15:16:20Z
```

This way you can determine the earliest-per-group records using:

```
WHERE t2.Date1 IS NULL
```

So, the final query will be:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.`key`, t1.Val1, t3.Val2, t1.Date1, t3.Date2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.`key` = t2.`key` AND t2.Date1 < t1.Date1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID AND t1.`key` = t3.`key` 
WHERE t2.Date1 IS NULL
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d2823/6)

Comment: Its giving me Val2 value as Null

Comment: @VectorJX This is not possible because `Table2` is `INNER`-joined to `Table1`. Perhaps you mistyped the table aliases?